# kubectl statement validity for deleting evicted pods which are older than one month

Tags: bash, kubectl

I'm trying to delete the evicted pods which are older than a month, I have the following statement but I have doubts about its validity, can you please check and advise back?

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | awk -F "d" '{print $1}' $6 | grep -E Evicted >>output.data | while read line; do ns=$(echo $line | cut -d , -f 1); pod=$(echo $line | cut -d , -f 2); age=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f 6); if [[$age -gt 30]]; then kubectl delete pod --dry-run='server' -n $ns $pod; fi done
```

Comment: We need a reproducible example. Please post an example of output of the commands `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` or `kubectl delete pod --dry-run='server' -n $ns $pod`

Comment: I advise you to indent the code of `awk` to make it readable.

Comment: @PierreFrançois:  the output of kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
 
west                            advert-editor-api-84bbc886f8-srh5w                                1/1     Running            0          5d19h
west                            data-abstraction-layer-cffd9cdc6-84x9m                            1/1     Running            0          14m
west                            flux-system-west-99fb96df8-mc2kv                                  1/1     Running            0          31m

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question to include this output. It that case, it will be possible to format the output in such a way that we can see where the lines break, which is not possible inside of a comment.